# How to mock chained function calls in python?

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm using the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library written by Michael Foord to help with my testing on a django application.

I'd like to test that I'm setting up my query properly, but I don't think I need to actually hit the database, so I'm trying to mock out the query.

I can mock out the first part of the query just fine, but I am not getting the results I'd like when I chain additional things on.

The function:

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_policies(policy_holder, current_user):
        if current_user.agency:
            return Policy.objects.filter(policy_holder=policy_holder, version__agency=current_user.agency).distinct()
        else:
            return Policy.objects.filter(policy_holder=policy_holder)
```

and my test: The first assertion passes, the second one fails.

```
    def should_get_policies_for_agent__user(self):
        with mock.patch.object(policy_models.Policy, "objects") as query_mock:
            user_mock = mock.Mock()
            user_mock.agency = "1234"
            policy_models.Policy.get_policies("policy_holder", user_mock)
            self.assertEqual(query_mock.method_calls, [("filter", (), {
                'policy_holder': "policy_holder",
                'version__agency': user_mock.agency,
            })])
            self.assertTrue(query_mock.distinct.called)
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the initial query_mock is returning a new mock after the .filter() is called, but I don't know how to capture that new mock and make sure .distinct() was called on it.

Is there a better way to be testing what I am trying to get at? I'm trying to make sure that the proper query is being called.

Comment: Please don't waste time mocking the Django queries.  Just create a "fixture" and run the real queries against your fixture data.  It's much simpler and produces much more useful test results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We've been using fixtures but are trying to move away from them in certain instances for two reasons. one: our models are complex with lots of relationships. setting up the fixtures for this particular case would need fixture data for users, companies, agencies, policyholders, policies, and versions. I don't need to actually run the query, I just need to make sure it is set up properly. two: our tests run much much slower using fixtures

Comment: @Aaron: We do this.  (1) run the built-in admin to create the data.  (2) do a dumpdata of the hand-built admin pages.  Our fixtures are small (dozens of rows at most), load very quickly, and save us trying to mock out Django itself.

Comment: @S.Lott how many tests do you have and how long do they take to run?

Comment: @Matthew J Morrison: Not a simple question.  We have a dozen or so distinct applications, each with many tests.  The entire test script (all tests) takes -- I think -- 12 minutes and has hundreds of tests.  The app I'm (supposed to be) working on now is 39 tests in 99 sec.  Of course, I could run an even smaller subset to focus on just the thing I'm changing.

Comment: @S.Lott of the 39 tests how many fixtures do you have? A minute and a half seems like a very long time to wait for so few tests. Sure, you can run a subset, but when you go back to run all of them there is no way I'd wait around for 12 minutes. I like to see ALL tests pass before I commit, If I have to wait 12 mins I'm going to stop running the tests all together, which means broken builds. Mocking away external dependencies (databases included) is crucial to unit testing.

Comment: "If I have to wait 12 mins I'm going to stop running the tests all together".  How sad.  "Mocking away external dependencies (databases included) is crucial".  Perhaps patience and discipline are also crucial.  Sorry, but testing is the *most important* part of coding.  To say that you would dispose of testing because of a timing issue is -- I think -- shabby.  You're certainly free to argue that testing is not the absolutely most important thing.  But when you argue that testing isn't important, you argue that trust and confidence aren't important either.  What's left?

Comment: "I like to see ALL tests pass before I commit". Same here.  I don't commit more than once or maybe twice a day.

Comment: @S.Lott I agree that writing tests are extremely important, but they shouldn't slow down development. Nobody should have to "be patient while the tests run", I should be able to run the tests quick, see they pass, commit and move on to the next thing very quickly. Waiting for a large test suite to run slows down rhythm too much for what it is worth, considering that if you remove external dependencies they could complete in a much shorter amount of time. I'm all for using fixtures and actual external dependencies, but not in a unit test setting.

Comment: "but they shouldn't slow down development".  They don't.  I'm not sure quite what you're talking about.  My machine does more than one thing at a time.  I find that I can write documentation while tests run.  Perhaps you need an OS that permits multi-tasking?  Also, since I often use subset tests, I can work on one thing while testing another.  I suppose your tests could be painfully slow and tie up your entire machine.  I find that taking the defaults works quite well, and testing using the Django framework -- with fixtures -- is very simple and fast.

Comment: @S.Lott : I assume you're not doing TDD if you think 12 minutes is ok.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Each mock object holds onto the mock object that it returned when it is called. You can get a hold of it using your mock object's return_value property.

For your example,

```
self.assertTrue(query_mock.distinct.called)
```

distinct wasn't called on your mock, it was called on the return value of the filter method of your mock, so you can assert that distinct was called by doing this:

```
self.assertTrue(query_mock.filter.return_value.distinct.called)
```

Comment: So simple... Thank you for providing a useful, clear answer. Much more helpful than the back and forth banter between you and S.Lott...